# Saving a model in ember without Ember data

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have an Ember project that I had been working on where I could save my model in my route:

```
            Ember.$.ajax({
            url: config.api.baseURL + 'propzone/' + model.name,
            type: 'PUT',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify(model),
            success: function() {
                // RENDER NOTIFICATION
                self.refresh();
            },
            error: function(err) {
                alert('Error: ' + err);
            }
        });
```

This did work fine until I updated Ember and Ember-cli.

Now I'm getting this error message:

> Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: You must use Ember.set() to set the `gallery` property (of [object Object]) to ``.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this might not be entirely related to the model save, but a possible bug in the framework. Does [this issue](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/ember-1-8-you-must-use-ember-set-to-set-the-property/6582) apply?

Comment: On my older version of Ember I could just make changes to my model and they would be saved on my ajax call. Now it appears I have to do an Ember.set(....) to have my changes saved.